# 日本語を含んだテキストファイルをソートするには？

Tags: ubuntu, shellscript

utf-8 のテキストファイルがあります。このファイルに対して `sort` コマンドを行っても、日本語がソートされないことに気が付きました。

```
 % cat test.txt
あ
い
う
え
お
 % cat test.txt | sort
あ
い
う
え
お
 % cat test2.txt
お
え
う
い
あ
 % cat test2.txt | sort
お
え
う
い
あ
```

日本語を含んだテキストファイルをするには、どうしたらいいでしょうか。

Comment: GNU coreutils に含まれる sort コマンド(バージョン 8.25)の場合、`printf 'お\nえ\nう\nい\nあ\n' | LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF-8 sort` とすると `あ\nい\nう\nえ\nお\n` になります。

Comment: ソート順はどのようなものを仮定してらっしゃるのでしょうか？　たとえば話を平仮名に限ったとしても、濁点のついた「が」が「き」より前なのか後なのか、あるいは「ゅ」のような拗音や、濁点を合字として表した「が」(U+304B U+3099)がどうなのか、は、何か決まりが無いと決められないと思います。Unicodeのコード順や文字の同一性判定仕様はありますが、必ずしもそれに沿っていることを意図した質問ではないかもしれないためのコメントです。

Comment: 参考: [Unicode照合アルゴリズム - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode%E7%85%A7%E5%90%88%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%82%BA%E3%83%A0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printf 'お\nえ\nう\nい\nあ\n' | LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF-8 sort
```

とすると

```
あ
い
う
え
お
```

になりました。